# R swap 2 data.table without using temporary variable

Tags: r, data.table, swap

I want to find a simple way to swap 2 data.table in R.

I could do it as below but I need to use temporary variable `tmp`

```
# Swap a and b
tmp <- copy(a)
a <- copy(b)
b <- copy(tmp)
```

Does R support any swap function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to R's copy-on-modify-only semantics, you can remove the `copy` from your expressions and it will still work and will not actually copy **data** with any version of R (the list answer will also not copy data starting from version 3.1):

```
dt1 = data.table(a = 1)
dt2 = data.table(b = 2)
address(dt1)
#[1] "000000000FDCA298"
address(dt2)
#[1] "000000000F7EC2E8"

tmp = dt1
dt1 = dt2
dt2 = tmp

address(dt1)
#[1] "000000000F7EC2E8"
address(dt2)
#[1] "000000000FDCA298"
```

Comment: Do you know what is different between `=` and `<-`. In my experience, both are assign operator but I think in some case its do not work in the same way.

Comment: @MinhHa there is no difference when assigning, but the `=` can also used to name variables in lists or functions, e.g. `list(a = c(1:4))` - there is an SO answer about it somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Is just not using a temporary variable going to do you any good? I mean you could do this without using a third variable:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(c = c(1,2), d = c(2,3))
df1 <- list(df1, df2)
df2 <- df1[[1]]
df1 <- df1[[2]]
df1
c d
1 1 2
2 2 3
df2
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

We're preserving both data.frames into a list instead of one of the two `data frames` then we can just swap the order by saving the other `data frame` into the second variable, then keeping what's left on the first variable.